# Who is the singer that sings in a Game of Thrones teaser trailer?

Tags: game-of-thrones

The teaser trailer I'm thinking of is very short and only shows visuals of the characters. But they do not go about speaking, only the woman's voice is singing. I have heard this song in other fantasy trailers, but I can't remember any of the lyrics!

Comment: Are you talking about season 1,2,etc? What season are you talking about.

Comment: Any chance of a link to these videos, including the Game of Thrones one? I've tried Googling a couple but they don't involve a woman singing at all. :)

Comment: Oh, oh your city, lies in dust, my friend?

Answer (score 9):

Do you mean this trailer?

If so then that's [Florence Welch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Florence_Welch) from [Florence and the Machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Florence_and_the_Machine) with their song [*Seven Devils*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceremonials).

If you mean this trailer:

Then that is Hannah Reid singing as part of the band [London Grammar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/London_Grammar) performing their cover of the [INXS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INXS) song [*Devil Inside*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devil_Inside_(INXS_song)).

Or if you mean this trailer:

Then that is Lizzy Plapinger from the band [MS MR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MS_MR) performing their song [*Bones*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qDpdpE00rfI).

If you mean another trailer then please clarify which one.

Comment: IIRC, there was a S4 teaser trailer that had Lorde's cover of *Everybody Wants To Rule the World*.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but none of these are it. Its a female vocalist with nothing else, no band, no instruments, just her voice.. very celtic humming, moody…  i feel like i saw it on a HBO teaser trailer, winter is coming. but i still can't find it. i hope i'm thinking of the right movie!

Comment: http://youtu.be/x21cMZdCQI0   Silly me, it was snow-white and the huntsman all along. thx :)

Comment: @jessica, Movie?;;; In any case, if that's the answer you should put it as an answer and accept it :) you are allowed to answer your own questions.

Answer (score 8):

The song is [Gone by Ioanna Gika](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6QS-Ia-EmIY) used in the Snow White and the Huntsman new movie.
It was also used as a season 3 premier of game of thrones in an HBO clip (still never found it)

Comment: I couldn't find a trailer for it with that song but this is a fan made compilation of clips from Game of Thrones with that song. Perhaps this is what you were thinking of: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PTMGZpK31mo